# TD Ameritrade API 'Get Option Chain' giving <Response [200]> but I'm getting JSONDecodeError: Expecting value?

Tags: python, json, api

After generating the access_token (which works when I use it on TD Ameritrade's API website) I'm trying to get option chains for a stock. I can get it to work on TD Ameritrade's API website, and I get an 'OKAY' response when I run my code, but no JSON data attached, any idea why? My relevant code is below.

```
content = requests.get(url = https://api.tdameritrade.com/v1/marketdata/chains, params = params_dictionary, headers = access_token)
print(content)
print(repr(content.text))
data = content.json()
print(data)
```

but for my output I get

```
<Response [200]>
''
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\GitHub\pythonfiles\TD Ameritrade API tests.py", line 98, in <module>
    data = content.json()

  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 900, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)

  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())

  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a mistake on my part unshown in my question. I was accidentally using 'https://api.tdameritrade.com/v1/marketdata/https://api.tdameritrade.com/v1/marketdata/chains' for my URL. I'm unsure how this didn't break things, but this was my issue.